# Is it OK if I assign *args to an instance attribute?

Tags: python

I am doing this in my class:

```
class BirdViewMetric(object):
    def __init__(self, metric_type, *args):
        self._metric_type = metric_type
        self._metrics = args
```

Is this safe? Should I assign a deep copy of `args` instead?

Comment: It's fine just as it is.

Comment: There isn't anything glaringly *unsafe* about it, but do you have a particular worry? `args` is just a tuple consisting of the variadic positional arguments passed to your `__init__`

Comment: From the documentation:  "If the form “*identifier” is present, it is initialized to a tuple receiving any excess positional parameters, defaulting to the empty tuple." Yes, there are other languages where varargs are an artificial construct on the stack.  Python isn't one of them.

Comment: What if someone does this: `args=[1,2,3,4,5]; bv=BirdViewMetric('type1', args); args.append(6)`?

Comment: @codeforester what about it? This applies to *any* mutable object you pass into a function. There is nothing unique about using variadic arguments. Note, in the case of `bv` it was passed a tuple of size one, with that list in it, i.e. in `__init__`, `args == ([1,2,3,4,5],)`

Comment: And you in fact *cannot* do `args.append(6)`.  `args` is a tuple and is immutable (though its elements may be mutable.)

Comment: @FrankYellin I believe they mean if the *caller* does `args.append`. But functions accept mutable arguments all the time, and generally don't defensively deepcopy them. It is the caller's responsibility not to do something silly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.  Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `*args` allows you to capture all of the arguments that are passed that don't fit into the parameters. When you assign it to `self._metrics`, you are actually assigning a tuple containing all of the arguments that went into args. Therefore, it is safe.

Example:

```py
def test(*args):
    return args
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = test(*a)
print(b) #(1, 2, 3, 4)
```